# How to display foreign key name in list table in Blazor Client Side

Tags: foreign-keys, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-client-side

I am trying to display a subject name for a course where I saved the subject from a database driven dropdown list in a client-side Blazor app. The value returns as a Guid instead of the subject name. Has anyone accomplished this with Blazor? I couldn't find anything in the Blazor documentation or any tutorials that could solve the issue I'm having. This is in Blazor client-side and I am using Entity Framework Core

This is what my Course model looks like in the Shared project:

```
public class Course
    {
        public Guid CourseID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CourseCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CourseName { get; set; }

        public string CourseSubject { get; set; }

        public string CourseCredits { get; set; }
    }
```

This is what my Subject model looks like in the Shared project:

```
public class Subject
    {
        public Guid SubjectID { get; set; }

        public string SubjectName { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my CourseData Data Access Model in the Server project:

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext ();

public IEnumerable<Course> GetAllCourses()
        {
            try
            {
                return db.Courses.ToList();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        } 
        public void AddCourse(Course course)
        {
            try
            {
                db.Courses.Add(course);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

This is my SubjectData Data Access Model in the Server project:

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext ();

        public IEnumerable<Subject> GetAllSubjects()
        {
            try
            {
                return db.Subjects.ToList();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }    
        public void AddSubject(Subject subject)
        {
            try
            {
                db.Subjects.Add(subject);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

This is my Course Controller in the Server project:

```
CourseData objcourse = new CourseData();

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/Courses/Courses")]
        public IEnumerable<Course> Index()
        {
            return objcourse.GetAllCourses();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/Courses/Create")]
        public void Create([FromBody] Course course)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
                objcourse.AddCourse(course);
        }
```

This is how I save the value in my Course creation page in my Client project:

```
@page "/Courses/Create"
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager NavigationManager

<h1>Add Course</h1>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="CourseCode" class="control-label">Course Code</label>
                <input for="CourseCode" class="form-control" @bind="@course.CourseCode" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="CourseName" class="control-label">Course Name</label>
                <input for="CourseName" class="form-control" @bind="@course.CourseName" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="CourseSubject" class="control-label">Subject</label>
                <select class="form-control" @bind="@course.CourseSubject">
                    <option></option>
                    @foreach (var subject in subjectList)
                    {
                        <option value="@subject.SubjectID">@subject.SubjectName</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="CourseCredits" class="control-label">Course Credits</label>
                <input for="CourseCredits" class="form-control" @bind="@course.CourseCredits" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" @onclick="@CreateCourse">Save</button>
                <button class="btn" @onclick="@cancel">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@functions {
    List<Subject> subjectList = new List<Subject>();

    Course course = new Course();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        subjectList = await Http.GetJsonAsync<List<Subject>>("api/Subjects/Subjects");
    }

    protected async Task CreateCourse()
    {
        await Http.SendJsonAsync(HttpMethod.Post, "/api/Courses/Create", course);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Courses/Courses");
    }

    void cancel()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Courses/Courses");
    }
}
```

And finally this is my Courses list page in my Client project where it returns the Guid for the subject name, for which I would like to show the subject name instead of it's Guid:

```
@page "/Courses/Courses"
@inject HttpClient Http
<h1>Courses</h1>
<p>
    <a href="/Courses/Create">Create New</a>
</p>
@if (courseList == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Course Code</th>
                <th>Course Name</th>
                <th>Subject</th>
                <th>Credits</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var course in courseList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@course.CourseCode</td>
                    <td>@course.CourseName</td>
                    <td>@course.CourseSubject</td>
                    <td>@course.CourseCredits</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href='/Courses/Edit/@course.CourseID'>Edit</a>  |
                        <a href='/Courses/Delete/@course.CourseID'>Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
@functions {
    Course[] courseList;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        courseList = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Course[]>
        ("/api/Courses/Courses");
    }
}
```

Database Context as requested:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"REMOVED-FOR-SECURITY");
            }
        }
    }
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers are good but let me give you something else to think about...

#### When writing Blazor apps try to think in terms of *components* more often than of *code*.

For example, let's say that the `Subjects` are static data that doesn't change a lot. So if every time you show a list, or want to build a dropdown for them, you're potentially going to have to make a database call or a SQL `JOIN`? So my first thought would be to create a lookup cache for GUID-to-Subject-name. And since this is Blazor if it's cached on the client you no longer need to make a database or API call - it's loaded once.

Then, since we're in Blazor, I'd create a `<SubjectName>` component, e.g.

```
   Subject: <SubjectName Id="@Model.SubjectId" />
```

The component uses the cache to get the value, it can handle a null value, it can handle an invalid subject ID. You've encapsulated a *lot* of behaviour and error handling in a single place, and can re-use that every time you need to map an ID to a subject name.

Similarly I'd create a `<SubjectDropdown>` component to show a list of subjects, again using the cache.

Comment: Thanks about improve answer and share knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You set `CourseSubject` with the `SubjectID` with is a Guid, so you get a Guid.
If you want to display the subject name either, request the subject by its Guid, or return the Subject in your course:

```cs
public class Course
{
    public Guid CourseID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CourseCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public string CourseSubject { get; set; }

    public string CourseCredits { get; set; }

    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<Course> GetAllCourses()
{
    try
    {
         return db.Courses
            .Include(c => c.Subject)
            .ToList();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
...
}


 @foreach (var course in courseList)
  {
      <tr>
          <td>@course.CourseCode</td>
          <td>@course.CourseName</td>
          <td>@course.Subject.SubjectName</td>
          <td>@course.CourseCredits</td>
          <td>
              <a href='/Courses/Edit/@course.CourseID'>Edit</a>  |
               <a href='/Courses/Delete/@course.CourseID'>Delete</a>
          </td>
      </tr>
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me. I get an Object reference not set to an instance of an object error. It also adds a SubjectID field to my Courses table. This remains empty when saving a course and the ID is still saved to the CourseSubject field. If I go the route I did in MVC where I would add a public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; } to the Subject model and change the CourseSubject to SubjectID in my Course model,the create course page breaks with no clear error of what is wrong.

Comment: Update your db, and check if the migration create the foreign key

Comment: It does create the foriegn key relationship when I add public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; } to the Subject model. I then manually created a course record in the database and put an existing subject's Guid in the foreign key field, but the table breaks and does not return anything

Comment: can you post your DbContext ?

Comment: Added the database context to the original post :)

Comment: I just did a quick test with this code and it works, I published it on github, as a sample : https://github.com/aguacongas/EF-Nav-Sample

Comment: I checked your Github sample. Thanks for the effort you have put in to answer my question. While the sample code works in a standard .net core app, it does not function in a Blazor client side application :)

Comment: But Lawrence, this is a sample for your API. It doesn't run on client side. You can't have a db on your client, you can't access to the file system and so on